# Postdoctoral references asked to provide recommendation letters - does it indicate the candidate passed a screening?

Tags: postdocs, reference-request

I recently applied for a postdoctoral position at a university, and provided a list of three references. Today the university asked them to write a recommendation letter for me. Would this typically indicate that the candidate passed some screening?
I'm asking because this is the first university that replies and it would suggest that my cover letter is not terrible.

Comment: There's no typical answer.

Comment: That's not a good way of determining that your cover letter is not terrible. As a rule of thumb, your cover letter is not terrible if you (a) explain why you're the right person for the job; (b) don't make silly mistakes (grammar, typos, including the wrong name and citing false information about the PI/department).

Answer (score 1):

While every university has its own processes it is likely that you passed at least some initial screening. But it might not be terribly significant. It might be nothing more than that the university wants to communicate directly with your references rather than some other way to obtain the letters.

If you get invited to an interview then it is much more likely that they find you "interesting". But at the moment, it probably just means that they put your application in a pile of folks not to be immediately rejected for reasons of obvious ill-fit. Good luck, but don't read too much in to it yet.